# move backend database for enterprise project management, Project Server 2007 installed on WSS 3.0

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, microsoft-project

I am a database administrator and I need to move SQL databases from one server to another for enterprise project management, Project Server 2007 installed on WSS 3.0 (both at patch level SP2 + Aug09 CU).

I know how to move databases but I don't know how to re-point the application to the new server.

Can anyone please help me?

-

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Move Content databases:**

> stsadm –o deletecontentdb –url
>   http://yoursiteurl –databasename
>   your_content_db –databaseserver
>   source_SQL_server
>
> stsadm –o addcontentdb –url
>   http://yoursiteurl –databasename
>   your_content_db –databaseserver
>   target_SQL_server

**Move Config databases:**

> stsadm -o deleteconfigdb
>
> stsadm –o setconfigdb -connect
>   –databaseserver target_SQL_server
>   -databasename   databasename -farmuser your_farm_sql_account -farmpassword
>   your_farm_sql_password

**source: http://sharepointsherpa.com/2008/04/18/sharepoint-2007-move-content-and-configuration-databases/

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't an INI or a config file or a setting in the application itself, can you cheat and use the HOSTS file on the application server to point the name of the old server to the new server?